# clean up json to avoid unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json

I send my json from server to client side, it became like below. I tried do JSON.stringify(json) and parse it back with JSON.parse() it doesn't go away. I also tried to do parse alone, it still contain strange character. What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: value needs to be in quotes `"`

Comment: @gurvinder372 it became code after it came to the cilent, not sure why does that happened

Comment: The problem is that whatever is GENERATING the JSON is HTML encoding the output.   You'll have to tell us what is sending that data. That's what needs fixed.

Comment: What's your backend? What library are you using to encode the content? How is the content being passed down to the browser? In the response body? Is it part of a URL?